# Returning a class member struct with a templated class

Tags: c++, class, struct, g++

I'm trying to create a function that returns a class-defined struct from a templated class. g++ give the error message `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token`. Here is the relevant code:

From BSTDict.cpp:

```
Node*& BSTDict<T, Compare>::add_helper(Node*& r, T key) { ... }
```

From BSTDict.hpp:

```
struct Node {
    T key;
    T data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

...

Node*& add_helper(Node*& r, T key);
```

I've done a lot of testing and I think the problem lies with Node (regardless of the reference and pointer). I've tried `BSTDict<T, Compare>::Node*& BSTDict<T, Compare>::add_helper(Node*& r, T key) { ... }` too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here are [BSTDict.hpp](http://pastebin.com/SVj61nka) and [BSTDict.cpp](http://pastebin.com/NaerC8Fc). They are part of a larger program.

Comment: There's no such thing like "templated class"; it's called "class template".

Comment: And 'member struct' is a 'nested type'

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew I'd get the terminology wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
    typename BSTDict<T, Compare>::Node*& 
    BSTDict<T, Compare>::add_helper(Node*& r, T key) 
    { 
       // ... 
    }
```

I'm not sure about `/*typename*/` being required there. I'd have to see more of your code (I had to make up the `template<>` qualifiers msyefl already :))

Comment: Thanks sehe, adding the (uncommented) `typename` did it! I've updated my post with link to the full files anyway.